# Short hand if statement in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've seen this question a few times, I've also seen the Ternary operator suggested and used.

I was wondering how I use the Ternary operator in my example and if it's the best way.

My if statement :

```
if (dateSel.stock_qty <= 20) {
   $(".stock_left").css("display", "block");
} else if (dateSel.stock_qty == 0) {
   // do nothing
}
```

I changed this to :

```
dateSel.stock_qty <= (20) ? "Y" : "N";
```

What does the `Y` and `N` refer to. Can I place functions within the quotes?

For this type of if statement, is a Ternary the shortest way to handle it or is there a better way.

Comment: Does `dateSel.stock_qty` have a custom property getter with a side effect? If it doesn't (and it definitely should not), then why bother with an `else if` in the first place?

Comment: The `else if` is impossible. It would get matched by the first `if`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/221/conditions/2184/ternary-operators#t=201607271355273249966

Comment: You seem overly concerned with how "short" the code is.

Comment: Using a ternary operator is most likely not the way to go here. Especially if you want your code to be readable.

Comment: @squint: I wish I could up-vote your comment more than once.

Comment: If you're filled with an irrepressible desire to have this shortened, you can do `dateSel.stock_qty <= 20 && $(".stock_left").css("display", "block");`. But the ternary operator is not going to help here.

Comment: It would be appropriate if you'd like to _either_ show or hide your element, depending on stock_qty: `$(".stock_left").css("display", dateSel.stock_qty <= 20 ? "block" : "hidden");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ternary isn't going to shorten the things there, since it needs the second part anyway, unlike regular if conditions. Also, ternary wasn't really designed for these purposes.

Go with this, just remove the else block and the brackets:

```
if(dateSel.stock_qty <= 20)$(".stock_left").css("display", "block");
```

Answer (score 0):

This type of if-statement? I think you do not need the `else if` block in this case, so you could just have one if-statement. A ternary would not help you here, since you wouldn't even want something after the `:`.

Answer (score 0):

From 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

- The Ternary is basically a way to write your IF statement in a simpler (or you can say a "cleaner") way. There isnt any real advantage. But if you want to use it it should look like this:

  dateSel.stock_qty <= (20) ? $(".stock_left").css("display", "block") :"0" ;

but be aware you can't include the "else if" part here! Just a pure "else" after the semicolon ':'

Edit: Changed semicolons and added number to satisfy the situation. Note that as discussed below it is not good practice to do this!

Comment: LOL that's the wonkiest link ever. Try the left-aligned english version [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: Zaid: You'll need to read the docs you linked more carefully.

Comment: Missed having the wrong-ish region for the link, Ouch!

Comment: Also what am I missing here @squint?

Comment: You have a semicolon after the  second operand making it a statement instead of an expression and the third operand is an empty statement. In other words, the grammar is `expr ? expr1 : expr2` but you have `expr ? statement : empty_statement`

Comment: In the example in the link it shows that it is possible to use statements in there.  as in `var stop = false, age = 16;

age > 18 ? location.assign("continue.html") : stop = true;` I still don't see why the code I posted wouldn't work.

Comment: But you are correct about the fact I added a few too many semicolons, Ops.

Comment: The `location.assign("continue.html")` is an expression. You just need to remove your semicolon. The `stop = true` is an assignment expression. Doesn't matter what the expression is, but it needs to be there. Terminating with `;` will be interpreted as an empty statement. You could put a numeric literal (for example) to satisfy the requirement, but that would be a hack to get it to work.

Comment: Thank you for hanging here with me explaining where I got it wrong. I appreciate it.